# Dense_rank in c# datatable

Tags: c#, dense-rank

How to implement `Dense_rank` function into the datatable in C#?

I tried with datarow loop but I want some efficient way preferably with lambda expression.

Comment: *"I tried with datarow-loop"* - so what's wrong with it? Have you faced any problems?

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: The only problem is to compare multiple columns (but not all) and multiple casting/unboxing. I think it could be an issue with big datatable.I am wondering if there is some sort of efficient way.

Comment: Apart from that maintaining order of columns for the partition is annoying.